# Azure Cloud Service + SQL Azure and firewall configuration issue

Tags: azure-sql-database

I'm facing the issue while creating a azure database in the local machine by sql server 2012 ,
this is my error:

### TITLE: Connect to Server

### Cannot connect to tcp:ServerName.database.windows.net.

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Login failed for user 'UserName'.
This session has been assigned a tracing ID of '041a1130-65a5-4ad6-91c0-02ff3b4fbca5'.  Provide this tracing ID to customer support when you need assistance. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is occurring might be due to following the following, I have specified how to overcome against each issue:

1. Check if your IP is added in the firewall, if not refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj553530.aspx
2. Check if you have configured the wrong IP in Azure Firewall. Try opening SQL Azure Management Studio online http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee621784.aspx#WinAzMgtPort where it asks you to add the IP in firewall.
3. If above is not working then check if the user credentials is correct, if you forgot the credentials then resetting it might help.